# How to use form_for with customized route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, resources

The custom routing:

```
resources :blog, controller: 'posts'
```

How do I rewrite this line `<%= simple_form_for(@post, blog_path) do |f| %>` to get rid of the below error?

```
TypeError in Posts#edit
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)
```

I also tried `<%= simple_form_for(blog_path(@post)) do |f| %>`, which gets rid of the error, but then if I want to edit the form the inputs are emptied of their saved data.

**posts_controller**

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if current_user.admin
      @post.save
      respond_with(@post)
    else
      flash[:success] = 'Get out of here.'
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can take a hash options, including url, so something like this:

**Edit: changed `blog_path` to `blogs_path`**. The `blog_path` is the show action, not the create action and therefore requires an id (and isn't a post path anyway). Try it out this way.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, url: blogs_path) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Hey Cruz. Thanks for your help. Problem with your answer though is if I try to create a new blog post I get the error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]` Any other ideas on how we can make form_for work with a customized route? Thanks again!

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com - did you ever solve this? Did my edit work, or is this still an issue?

Comment: Hey Cruz I'll give you the checkmark :) since your's worked for the specific problem I posed, but overall I found that this worked best for me in routes.rb: `resources :blog, to: 'posts' resources :posts` That way I get best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this applies, but a really cool feature I found the other day was [`.becomes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/becomes) - where you can change the "class" of your object so that Rails treats it in a different way:

> This can be used along with record identification in Action Pack to allow, say, Client < Company to do something like render partial: `@client.becomes(Company)` to render that instance using the companies/company partial instead of clients/client.

So...

If you had a `Blog` model, and wanted each `@post` to be treated as such (again, I don't know if this is your setup at all), you could do the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post.becomes(Blog) do |f| %>
```

I'll delete if inappropriate; it's come in handy quite a lot for me.

---

**Update**

If you'd like your `posts_path` to be blog (IE `url.com/blog/1`), you'll want to look at using the [`path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) option for the routes generator:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts, path: "blog", as: :blog # -> url.com/blogs/2
```

Comment: Hey Rich thanks again for your help. I don't have a blog model. I just have posts, but I like the way blog looks better in the url. Here's the thing now, when I used Cruz's suggestion I'm able to edit, but not create now. Any ideas here? For example if I just put `<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>` I get the error `undefined method 'posts_path'`. This is because due to my routes change it is now `blog_index_path`

Comment: I just read this after editing my above answer. Can you show your routes file?